# side preview tinyMCE content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4

I need to show live preview on same page. I need to show blending of content of other input values with content inside tinyMCE text area in a side div as user formats the text or changes other input values(text/select/checkbox etc).

Would anybody give me direction to implement that?

Check https://app.classeur.io/#!/files/zvbiZEbizyUHb2aUS9xP and click on Side Preview link to see behavior which I need for tinyMCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I implemented by using `change` and `keyup` events provided by TinyMCE

Here is a snippet of the configuration.

```
tinyMCE.init({
      selector: "textarea.tinymce",
      toolbar: ["undo redo | bold italic | styleselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent","link image media | code"],
      plugins: "image imagetools link paste media code",
      setup: function(ed) { 
        ed.on('change', function(e) {  
          previewContent(ed.getContent()); 
        }); 

        ed.on('keyup', function(e) { 
          previewContent(ed.getContent()); 
        }); 
      }
});
```